# Why is a nullable rowversion column is semantically equivalent to a varbinary(8)?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sqldatatypes

This [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=sql.90).aspx) states:

> A nonnullable rowversion column is semantically equivalent to a
> binary(8) column. A nullable rowversion column is semantically
> equivalent to a varbinary(8) column.

Given that a nonnullable rowversion column is semantically equivalent to a binary(8) column, why say a nullable rowversion column is semantically equivalent to a varbinary(8) column and not a nullable binary(8) column?

Does this imply a nullable rowversion column isn't semantically equivalent to a nullable binary(8) column?

My particular example is that I will have a table that will contain copies of rows from other tables. Some source tables have a rowversion and others don't. Therefore, the "rowversion" column in my table must accept null values. I want to understand why (or if) the column should be varbinary(8) null instead of binary(8) null.

Comment: @Andomar I've updated my question to explain why I would like to know.

Comment: Great, it's better now.  Can't retract a close vote though.

Comment: A column of type `binary(8)` will **always** contain 8 bytes of storage - regardless of what's stored inside it - even `NULL`. A nullable version thereof - `varbinary(8)` - however will occupy only as much space as really needed (plus some overhead).

Comment: I think the documentation is just wrong here. It is stored in the fixed length portion of the row even if the table is declared as `ROWVERSION NULL`. @marc_s Can it ever be null? `CREATE TABLE #T(C ROWVERSION NULL);INSERT INTO #T VALUES(NULL);SELECT * FROM #T;DROP TABLE #T` still returns a `NOT NULL` value despite the explicit insertion of `NULL`

Comment: @MartinSmith: hmmm.... even the 2012 version of the docs still contains that same statement. Of course you're right - the contents of the `rowversion` column will never be null - but the column itself can be declared nullable or non-nullable (not that it makes a lot of sense - but it's possible)

Comment: @marc_s Sorry I think I understand what your original comment was getting at. In the OP's destination table they should declare `binary` if they expect most to be `NOT NULL` as there is a two byte additional overhead for the `varbinary` but otherwise they can save space if most will be null. So `@Ɖiamond ǤeezeƦ` what percentage of rows will contain a value for this?

Comment: @marc_s Initially I expect 50% of rows will be `NULL`. However, over this will decrease to ~30% as I know most future data sources will have a rowversion column.

Comment: @ƉiamondǤeezeƦ: I guess as long as you're above 25% (the overhead for the `varbinary` datatype), I'd go with `varbinary(8)`

Comment: Thanks marc_s and Martin Smith. Would either of you like to turn these comments into an answer for some points? :)

Comment: My guess is that you can define rowversion as nullable or nonnullable even though you can't put Null into it anyway. Therefore one can differentiate the two situations internally and so ROWVERSION nullable is varbinary while nonnullable ROWVERSION is binary.

Answer (score 1):

A binary(8) is a binary that has EXACTLY 8 bytes.
A varbinary(8) is a binary that has upto 8 bytes.
A null is 0 bytes.
It has to be a form that can have 0 or 8 bytes.
Thus it has to be varbinary.

Comment: Eh… I don't buy it. Specifically, I can have a nullable binary(8) (or any other fixed-width data type).

Comment: What's not to buy?  Null values are recorded in individual bits on a separate byte for the data row.  The first nullable column  adds a byte to the storage, and each eighth nullable thereafter adds a byte to the storage.  'Null ness ' is figuratively stored on the 'header' of the row.  Once that bit for null is added for it to be null, it has the same storage as a varbinary.

Comment: I'm saying that the nullable characteristic of a column and whether it's a varying length column are orthogonal concepts. Specific to this case, why does the nullability of the rowversion column necessarily imply that it be a varbinay(8) NULL and not binary(8) null? The former implies that it could be a binary value of any length up to (and including) 8 bytes (or null) while the latter implies that it can be a binary value of 8 bytes (or null).